# Implementing the range object as an iterator using generator function

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, iteration, generator

I'm new to Python and I am trying to implement the range() object with positive step values as an iterator using a generator function in Python. I have already implemented this iterator by defining a class:

```
    class ranges:
        def __init__(self, start, stop, step):
            self.start = start - step
            self.stop = stop
            self.step = step
        def __iter__(self):
            return self
        def __next__(self):
            self.start = self.start +self.step
            if self.step > 0:
                if self.start < self.stop:
                    return self.start
                raise StopIteration
            if self.step ==0:
                return self.start - self.step
```

But when I try to create this iterator using a generator function, the program fails prematurely.

```
    def range(start, stop, step):
        range.counter = range.counter + 1
        if step == 0:
            yield start
        elif step > 0:
            if range.counter == 1 and start < stop:
                yield start
            elif (start + step) < stop:
                start = start + step
                yield start
    range.counter = 0

    for i in range(3, 11 , 2):
        print(i)
```

The output should be 3, 5, 7, 9 but the output displayed is just 3.

Comment: Why do you think `range` should return more than once?  It chooses one of the 3 yields when called, and does nothing after that.

Comment: like @ScottHunter said your generator will yield once. You need to create a loop in your generator function.

Comment: How would I make it return values as long as the for loop is iterating through it?

Comment: @AnuragSaksena the loop must be in the generator function.. around all the logic for your yeilds.. Remember to have a exit condition or you will loop forever tho.

Comment: For positive step values, all you need is `def range(start, stop, step): while start < stop and step > 0: yield start; start += step`. It makes no sense to accept a step of zero, since that would loop forever.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Unless one *wanted* it to loop forever.

Comment: @ScottHunter But then it wouldn't be a *range*, which normally implies a beginning and end.